# Creating new object with dynamic variables in PHP

Tags: php, dynamic-variables, objectinstantiation

I want to create a new object using this

```
$procedure = new ${$s.'\\'.$p};
```

It doesn't work. Why isn't this possible?

Comment: I thin it is because of extra `$` before `{`.

Comment: @tereško That's a [variable variable](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Comment: @Michael No, '\' is invalid syntax, as for "\\" it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @Michael, `"\"` is also the escape character. If you do single slash it will escape `'` or `"` of the string and will cause a parse error.

Comment: @Michael , in that case it would be an extremely bad practice ... i try to assume unintentional stupid mistake , before intentional harmful code convention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you

```
$name = "$s\\$p";
$procedure = new $name;
```

?

Also `${$s.'\\'.$p}` means a variable, with a variable name that is clearly not good. If you are, and I think you are, trying to get something like  an instance of `Namespace\Class` you should try with the code below.

I think that the `{}` shortcut only works with this syntax `${}` which is clearly referring to a variable. So you cannot use it for instantiating new objects.

Comment: I just want to understand. Besides, the first one is more compact.

Comment: @x74x61, It have a strange behavior probably because of some problem in the namespace. I tried also with `new {$s.'\\'.$p}` but didn't work. If you have to use this thing so many times that you need a shortcut, maybe there's something wrong in your application.

Comment: Yeah. however This is still is self-modifing code which is an awful idea to begin with.